# how to add a select box in a region of an created page in drupal

Tags: drupal

I want to create a list box in a region that has been created by me. Any help would be highly appreciated! I dont understand how to go about it. How can I add just a list box in the existing page?

Answer (score 0):

You should create block (html or php filters should be enabled), put there your list box html code, then place this block into region.
**But, using drupal way is recommend - drupal api** - create simple module, add form function with list box (select field) and call this form from block hook.